# Using Join but the value was multiples

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables like this.

Table A has blank value in statusID 202

| StatusID | CallID | **ContactID** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202 |  | 65490 |
| 302 | 1029-2134 | 65490 |

Table B

| DateTime | SessionID | **ContactID** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-15 02:29 | 0341-3124 | 65490 |
| 2023-05-15 02:30 | 1029-2134 | 65490 |

I used left join A.ContactID = B.ContactID but it returns multiple valueS like this :

| **ContactID** | **CallID** | **Status ID** | **DateTime** | **SessionID** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65490 |  | 202 | 2023-05-15 02:29 | 0341-3124 |
| 65490 | 1029-2134 | 302 | 2023-05-15 02:30 | 1029-2134 |
| 65490 |  | 202 | 2023-05-15 02:29 | 0341-3124 |
| 65490 | 1029-2134 | 302 | 2023-05-15 02:30 | 1029-2134 |

What's query to show data like this ? Expected Table :

| **ContactID** | **CallID** | **Status ID** | **DateTime** | **SessionID** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65490 |  | 202 | 2023-05-15 02:29 | 0341-3124 |
| 65490 | 1029-2134 | 302 | 2023-05-15 02:30 | 1029-2134 |

I also tried DISTINCT but the result still have multiple data.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  ContactID,
  CallID,
  StatusID,
  DateTime,
  SessionID
from TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON A.ContactID = B.ContactID
```

Comment: **SELECT DISTINCT ContactID, CallID, StatusID, DateTime,SessionID from TableA A JOIN TableB B ON A.ContactID = B.ContactID** @Charlieface

Comment: You could join on `CallId` also. The problem is: what do you do with the the ones where `CallId` is null? What do you want to happen with rows 1 and 3 from TableA, what logic would make you use only one of them?

Comment: If I use join in **CallID** the expected row 1 will not show. The point is I want to get result like expected table @Charlieface

Comment: But why? Why should row 1 show and not row 3? They are identical, there is no logical you have described to include one and not the other. **Describe** the steps/logic you want to take, to show row 1, 2 and 4 but not 3.

Comment: You need to explain the logic - are you assuming that the earliest session by time belongs to the earliest status?

Comment: Why do you think the first row of the first table should be joined with the first row of the second table?